# Restrict individual category combinations

Tags: plugins, categories

While assigning multiple categories to a post, I need to restrict the category choices on a post depending on what other categories have already been assigned to the particular post.

For example, lets say we have categories A, B and C.
For any post, we want to restrict having both categories B and C. So posts may have the following assignments:

- A, B, C
- A, B
- A, C

**No post** should have B **and** C.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to prevent saving altogether or you want to adjust the categories on save?

Comment: Any logic behind that? How you decide which combination is inappropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've had a couple minutes free time, so I wrote up a small plugin. ;)

---

The following goes into a new plugin file `tf-restrict-categories/tf-restrict-categories.php`:

#### The introduction

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Restrict Categories
 * Description: Individually restrict category combinations.
 * License: MIT
 * License URI: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 * Text Domain: tf-restrict-categories
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */


if (! class_exists('TFRestrictCategories')) :


/**
 * Main (and only) class.
 */
class TFRestrictCategories {

    /**
     * Plugin instance.
     *
     * @type    object
     */
    protected static $instance = null;


    /**
     * basename() of global $pagenow.
     *
     * @type    string
     */
    protected static $page_base;


    /**
     * Plugin textdomain.
     *
     * @type    string
     */
    protected $textdomain = 'tf-restrict-categories';


    /**
     * Plugin option name.
     *
     * @type    string
     */
    protected $option_name = 'tf_restrict_categories';


    /**
     * Plugin settings page name.
     *
     * @type    string
     */
    protected $settings_page_name = 'tf-restrict-categories';


    /**
     * Plugin settings page.
     *
     * @type    string
     */
    protected $settings_page;
```

#### The basics

```
    /**
     * Constructor. Registers activation routine.
     *
     * @hook    wp_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(__CLASS__, 'activation'));
    } // function __construct


    /**
     * Get plugin instance.
     *
     * @hook    wp_loaded
     * @return  object TFRestrictCategories
     */
    public static function get_instance() {
        if (null === self::$instance)
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    } // function get_instance


    /**
     * Registers uninstall routine.
     *
     * @hook    activation
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function activation() {
        register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, array(__CLASS__, 'uninstall'));
    } // function activation


    /**
     * Checks if the plugin has to be loaded.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public static function has_to_be_loaded() {
        global $pagenow;

        if (empty($pagenow))
            return false;

        self::$page_base = basename($pagenow, '.php');

        // Load plugin for all admin pages
        return is_admin();
    } // function has_to_be_loaded


    /**
     * Registers plugin actions and filters.
     *
     * @hook    wp_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function init() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_settings_page'));
        add_action('wp_insert_post', array($this, 'restrict_categories'));

        $pages = array(
            'edit',
            'post',
            'post-new',
        );
        if (in_array(self::$page_base, $pages))
            add_action('admin_print_scripts-posts_page_tf-restrict-categories', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));

        if ('plugins' === self::$page_base)
            add_filter('plugin_action_links_'.plugin_basename(__FILE__), array($this, 'add_settings_link'));

        if ('options' === self::$page_base)
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_setting'));
    } // function init


    /**
     * Wrapper for get_option().
     *
     * @param   string $key Option name.
     * @param   mixed $default Return value for missing key.
     * @return  mixed|$default Option value.
     */
    protected function get_option($key = null, $default = false) {
        static $option = null;
        if (null === $option) {
            $option = get_option($this->option_name, false);
            if (false === $option)
                $option = array(
                );
        }

        if (null === $key)
            return $option;

        if (! isset($option[$key]))
            return $default;

        return $option[$key];
    } // function get_option
```

#### This is where the action is

```
    /**
     * Adds custom settings page to posts settings.
     *
     * @hook    admin_menu
     * @return  void
     */
    public function add_settings_page() {
        $this->settings_page = add_posts_page('Restrict Categories', 'Restrict Categories', 'manage_categories', $this->settings_page_name, array($this, 'print_settings_page'));
    } // function add_settings_page


    /**
     * Prints settings page.
     *
     * @see     add_settings_page()
     * @return  void
     */
    public function print_settings_page() {
        $this->load_textdomain();
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Restrict Categories</h2>
            <div class="tool-box">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('options.php'); ?>">
                    <?php
                    settings_fields($this->option_name);
                    $args = array(
                        'hide_empty' => 0,
                    );
                    if (count($categories = get_categories($args))) {
                        $option = $this->get_option($this->option_name, array());
                        ?>
                        <table id="tf-restrict-categories" class="widefat">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                        ?>
                                        <th><?php echo $category->name; ?></th>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $alternate = true;
                                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                    $class = ($alternate) ? ' class="alternate"' : '';
                                    $alternate = ! $alternate;
                                    ?>
                                    <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                                        <td id=""><?php echo $category->name; ?></td>
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($categories as $second_category) {
                                            ?>
                                            <td id="restrict-category-<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>-<?php echo $second_category->term_id; ?>">
                                                <?php
                                                if ($category->term_id !== $second_category->term_id) {
                                                    $checked = (
                                                        isset($option[$category->term_id]) && isset($option[$category->term_id][$second_category->term_id])
                                                        || isset($option[$second_category->term_id]) && isset($option[$second_category->term_id][$category->term_id])
                                                    );
                                                    $checked = ($checked) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
                                                    $disabled = (isset($option[$second_category->term_id]) && isset($option[$second_category->term_id][$category->term_id]));
                                                    $disabled = ($disabled) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
                                                    ?>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>-<?php echo $second_category->term_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->option_name; ?>[<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>][<?php echo $second_category->term_id; ?>]" value="1"<?php echo $checked.$disabled; ?> />
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    } else
                        _e("No categories found.", 'tf-restrict-categories');
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $this->unload_textdomain();
    } // function print_settings_page


    /**
     * Restricts categories according to stored plugin settings.
     *
     * @hook    wp_insert_post
     * @param   int $id Post ID.
     * @return  void
     */
    public function restrict_categories($id) {
        $args = array(
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'orderby' => 'term_id'
        );
        if (
            count($option = $this->get_option($this->option_name, array()))
            && count($categories = wp_get_object_terms($id, 'category', $args))
        ) {
            foreach ($option as $master_key => $restrict)
                foreach($restrict as $restrict_key => $v)
                    if (in_array($master_key, $categories))
                        foreach($categories as $key => $category)
                            if ($category === $restrict_key)
                                unset($categories[$key]);

            wp_set_object_terms($id, $categories, 'category');
        }
    } // function restrict_categories


    /**
     * Adds a link to the settings to the plugin list.
     *
     * @hook    plugin_action_links_{$file}
     * @param   array $links Already existing links.
     * @return  array
     */
    public function add_settings_link($links) {
        $settings_link = array(
            '<a href="'.admin_url('edit.php?page='.$this->settings_page_name).'">'.__("Settings").'</a>'
        );

        return array_merge($settings_link, $links);
    } // function add_settings_link


    /**
     * Enqueues necessary script files.
     *
     * @hook    admin_print_scripts-posts_page_tf-restrict-categories
     * @return  void
     */
    public function enqueue_scripts() {
        $this->load_textdomain();
        wp_enqueue_script('tf-restrict-categories-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/tf-restrict-categories.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'js/tf-restrict-categories.js'), true);
        $this->unload_textdomain();
    } // function enqueue_scripts


    /**
     * Registers setting for custom options page.
     *
     * @hook    admin_init
     * @return  void
     */
    public function register_setting() {
        register_setting($this->option_name, $this->option_name, array($this, 'save_setting'));
    } // function register_setting


    /**
     * Prepares option values before they are saved.
     *
     * @param   array $data Original option values.
     * @return  array Sanitized option values.
     */
    public function save_setting($data) {
        $sanitized_data = $this->get_option();
        if (isset($data) && ! empty($data))
            $sanitized_data[$this->option_name] = $data;
        else
            unset($sanitized_data[$this->option_name]);

        return $sanitized_data;
    } // function save_setting
```

#### The end

```
    /**
     * Loads plugin textdomain.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     */
    protected function load_textdomain() {
        return load_plugin_textdomain($this->textdomain, false, plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/languages');
    } // function load_textdomain


    /**
     * Remove translations from memory.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    protected function unload_textdomain() {
        unset($GLOBALS['l10n'][$this->textdomain]);
    } // function unload_textdomain


    /**
     * Deletes plugin data on uninstall.
     *
     * @hook    uninstall
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function uninstall() {
        delete_option(self::get_instance()->option_name);
    } // function uninstall

} // class TFRestrictCategories


if (TFRestrictCategories::has_to_be_loaded())
    add_action('wp_loaded', array(TFRestrictCategories::get_instance(), 'init'));


endif; // if (! class_exists('TFRestrictCategories'))
```

---

The following goes into a new plugin file `tf-restrict-categories/js/tf-restrict-categories.js`:

#### The JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#tf-restrict-categories [type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (! $this.is(':disabled')) {
            var n = this.id.split('-');
            $('#tf-restrict-categories [type="checkbox"][name$="\\['+n[1]+'\\]\\['+n[0]+'\\]"]')
                .attr('disabled', $this.is(':checked'))
                .attr('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
        }
    });

});
```

---

Copy&Paste the code into the two files, upload to your `plugins` folder, activate the plugin and find the new settings page.

Happy restricting. :)

---

Okay, okay, some words of explaining...

The plugin works as follows. On the settings page, we define some category combination. Let's say, we want to have the rule *If 'Cat A' is present, do NOT allow 'Cat C'*. This can be achieved by checking the checkbox in the **row *Cat A*** and **column *Cat C***. This means: the row category is the master category, and the column category will be restricted.
Of course, you can have multiple combinations with *Cat A* (and multiple other categories).

When saving/updating a post (or, to be more precise: when **having saved/updated** a post), the categories are checked against the stored plugin settings - and adapted.

Anything else?

Comment: wow don't know to thank you enough will try it tonight

Comment: Impressive that you also created a settings page ;-) You should consider adding this to github to make it easier to use/test. +1 for the effort.

Comment: How can I adjust this so it works with a custom post type?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any hook that you can leverage to alter the categories going in when `wp_create_post` or `wp_update_post` are called.

However, you can always hook on the `wp_insert_post` action to update categories after a post is saved or updated:

```
function update_post_categories( $postID, $post, $is_update ) {
   $categories = wp_get_object_terms( $postID, 'category' );

   // Figure out which categories are invalid,
   // Put only the valid categories in $new_categories...

   wp_set_object_terms( $postID, $new_categories, 'category', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'update_post_categories', 10, 3 );
```

What this snippet above does is fetch the categories that would be assigned to a post, leaves only the ones that should be assigned in `$new_categories`, and then over-writes the categories for that post.

As you can see, I left out the logic to figure out which categories are valid, since you didn't describe what that logic is.